# how i navigate between pages in C#

Tags: c#, windows-store-apps

How can I navigate forms within the window (I have a button called settings, so when I click it, it should open up within  a new window?
I used this code, but I doesn't work out with me

```
Private void Button_Click_4 (object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{          
    NavigationService Nov = NavigationService. GetNavigationService (this); 
    Nov.Navigate (new Uri ("Window1. xaml", UriKind. RelativeOrAbsolute));
}
```

Comment: Define "doesn't work".  Maybe that space in the file name is resulting in an error?

Answer (score 0):

Try this line of code:

```
this.Frame.Navigate(typeof(Window1.xaml));
```

Reference: [MSDN: Navigating between pages (XAML)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/hh771188.aspx)